# C# does not recognize two variables

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in C#. However for some reason the program does not recognize 2 variables. Which are on line 52 of this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number: ");
            string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
            //Convert the string to a integer and check if it contains a number
            try
            {
                int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(num1);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That was not a number!");
            }
            catch (OverflowException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wow, not so many numbers..");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press / * + or -: ");
            string symbol = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number: ");
            String num2 = Console.ReadLine();
            //Convert the string to a integer and check if it contains a number
            try
            {
                int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(num2);
            }
            catch(FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That was not a number!");
            }
            catch(OverflowException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'Wow, not so many numbers..");
            }

            //check the symbol

            if(symbol == "+")
            {
                long result = AddNumber(number1, number2);
            }
            else if (symbol == "-")
            {

            }
        }

        //functions
        public int AddNumber(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }

        public int SubstractNumber(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 - number2;
            return result;
        }

        public int DevideNumber(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 / number2;
            return result;
        }

        public int MultiNumber(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 * number2;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And declared on line 18 and 37.

Comment: Also, you probably don't mean `SubstractNumber` or `DevideNumber`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is reasonable, because both the varaibles are local in the try blocks that are declared. You have to declare them both outside the `try` blocks, in which they are currently declared, in order to be "visible" on line 52. You could do this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     int number1;
     int number2;

     // ....

     try
     {
         number1 = Convert.ToInt32(num1);
     }

     // ...

     try
     {
         number2 = Convert.ToInt32(num1);
     }

     // ...

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks. That takes care off that error.
But i now get this error on line 52:
Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Calculator.Program.AddNumber(int, int)'

Comment: @Dieter91 that is because you are trying to call an instance function from a static function.  Make your operation functions static to resolve this issue (i.e. `public static int AddNumbers(...)`)

Comment: @Dieter91 you welcome dude ! I am glad thah I helped.